# Deactivate XML validation in SAX-Parser

Tags: xml, validation, sax

I want to parse a xml String in a fast way. If the xml does not contain the value I'm looking for I will just ignore the xml. So I need no xml validation, no object bindings, etc.
I just want to read one specific value in a xml.

I decided to use a SAX-parser.
The problem that I have is that I get validation errors, so I'm trying to deactivate the validation but it doesn't work so far.
Any suggestions?

Parsing code:

```
private String parseXml(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    saxParserFactory.setValidating(false);
    saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    saxParserFactory.setXIncludeAware(false);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl",true);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/use-entity-resolver2", false);
    saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    XmlResponseSaxHandler handler = new XmlResponseSaxHandler();
    saxParser.parse(xml, handler);
    return handler.getValue();
}
```

Handler-snippet:

```
@Override
public InputSource resolveEntity(String arg0, String arg1) throws IOException, SAXException {
    //Do not download dtd
    return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
}
```

Error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cos-nonambig: "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#":Reference und WC[##other:"http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd"] (oder Elemente aus ihrer Substitutionsgruppe) verletzen 'Unique Particle Attribution'. Bei der Validierung für dieses Schema würde eine Mehrdeutigkeit für diese beiden Partikel erstellt.
```

Comment: What does the input XML look like?

Comment: Try adding `factory.setSchema(null);` as it looks like the message is from schema validation and not DTD.